# Should I stream html files instead of just render?

Tags: node.js, express, stream, response

I am experimenting with node.js/express.js and thought to pipe html files to a request instead of just render.

I hope to achieve better performance, and html files will load faster, the first time.

```
//instead of
res.render('form',{title:'Login',userField:'Username',passField:'Password',photo: photo});

//I do
var path  = 'views/form.ejs';
var stream = fs.createReadStream(path);
stream.pipe(res);
This is actually about 10ms faster, even with a small file (385 bytes). I am developing so my files are still really
```

small.

The only con I find is that I cannot embed EJS data in the response like userField:'Username'

1- Am I using the pipe right in this case?

2- Are there any other pros and cons?

3- Am I overkilling it? Should I just use render because the differences are small, or in slow connections with

large html, the pipe actually saves the day?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Those 10ms are probably the time that it takes to actually render the template, a step that doesn't happen when you're piping the template in the way you're doing (which sends back the template as-is, and not its rendered form).

Rendering a template, at least with EJS, is a synchronous operation: Express needs to wait for it to finish before it can send back a response, and I don't see any possibility to stream a rendered EJS template in a way that would make it faster than just calling `res.render()`.

However, in my experience it's pretty fast, and there are some Express settings (like [`view cache`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set), which is enabled in production and disabled in development environments) that will help speed things up.